# Compute lower tail probability from upper tail - bivariate normal

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y$ be bivariate normal with correlation $\rho$.  I'd like to compute $\mathbb{P}(X \leq x, Y \leq y)$, but I have only a function (implemented on a computer) that returns $\mathbb{P}(X \geq x, Y \geq y)$.  Is there a simple relation between these two I can use to obtain the former from the latter?  Sorry if this is a basic question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the symmetry of a bivariate normal distribution about the mean $$P(X \le x, Y \le y)= P(X \ge 2\mu_X- x, Y \ge 2\mu_Y- y).$$